# StructureMap and Generics - How do I specify a default constructor?

Tags: c#, generics, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I have a generic interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T> { ... }
```

I have an implementation like this:

```
public class Repository<T> {
    public Repository<T>() { ... }
}
```

StructureMap (v 2.6.3) is configured like this:

```
For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(Repository<>));
```

When I try and pull an `IRepository<Something>` out of StructureMap, I get a `Repository<Something>` as expected. **Hooray!**

Now I've added a second constructor, and the implementation looks like this:

```
public class Repository<T> {
    public Repository<T>() { ... }
    public Repository<T>(string database) { ... }
}
```

When I try and get an `IRepository<Something>` now, I get an exception because it defaults to trying to use the new constructor with the parameter. **Boo!**

How can I change my StructureMap configuration so that it knows to use the parameter-less constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by marking the constructor you want StructureMap to use with the [DefaultConstructor] attribute. As you can see on the [StructureMap documentation](http://docs.structuremap.net/ConstructorAndSetterInjection.htm), it is greedy by default.

Comment: Yeah, I found that solution... However, I DON'T want to have to change my Repository class unless I really have to. It seems strange to have to tightly couple the implementation to a specific IOC container.

Comment: There is no way to do this for an open generic type. As a nasty kludge you could pass in a default value using CtorDependency e.g. x.For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(Repository<>)).CtorDependency<string>("database").Is(null); and then handle it accordingly. What is the database string used for and why don't you want your container to fulfill it?